# Google login without installign the glassware

Tags: google-mirror-api

I'm developing a glassware and I need some advices about the user login process.
I'm currently using this scopes:

```
SCOPES = ('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/glass.timeline '
      'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/glass.location '
      'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login '
      'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me '
      'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email')
```

in order to have the user login and install the glassware.
Now put the case that I closed the registrations but I want to give the already registered users a way to login to his/her preferences. 
What should I do? 
By exposing a login link with the same scopes i'm also allowing for non register users to add the glassware to their account.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Have you stored information about the already registered users in your server back-end?

If so you can check against that list after a user signs in, and only allow already registered users to access further services.